# How do I setup live code reload with featherjs?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

How do I setup live code reload, kind of like meteor, with featherjs?

Comment: It's poor form to downvote without giving feedback. A downvote tells the user "bad", but it doesn't tell the user why. Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 3):

Nodemon installs automatically via CLI. To run it just type `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Install `nodemon` in your app directory:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Step 2. Add the following to your `package.json` file, in the scripts section:

```
...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run eslint && npm run mocha",
    "dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/",
    "eslint": "eslint src/. test/. --config .eslintrc.json",
    "start": "node src/",
    "mocha": "mocha test/ --recursive"
  }
...
```

Step 3. Run the script using:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Isn't calling `nodemon src/` by default is watching to the `src directory`? so `--watch src` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a featherjs application in typescript, you need to use `ts-node-dev` to enable hot-reload for your application.

Add it by running the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev ts-node-dev
```

Next step is just to add the following script to your `package.json`

```
"start": "ts-node-dev --no-notify --exit-child src/"
```

If there is a better way, please feel free to reply to this thread for future references.